# comparar datas dentro da consulta sql

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

preciso comparar a data cadastrada no banco +10 dias com a data atual e exibir o aluno que a data atual for maior que os 10 dias, mas isso dentro da consulta sql.
Existe alguma função para isso?
Eu tentei isso, sem sucesso.

```
$dataMais10 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days'));
SELECT aluno,title,dt_banco FROM liberar WHERE dt_banco < {$dataMais10}
```

OBS. Eu nao posso recuperar o dt_banco antes da consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será algo deste género?

```
SELECT  aluno,title
    ,   dt_banco 
FROM    liberar 
WHERE   DATE_ADD(dt_banco, INTERVAL 10 DAY) < CURDATE()
```

Basicamente a consulta está a obter todos os registos da tabela `liberar` em que o valor da coluna `dt_banco` + 10 dias é inferior à data atual.

Comment: nossa isso resolveu, eu só mudei o < para > pois preciso exibir o aluno em que a data atual é maior que os 10 dias, aí funcional.